# PHP Newsletter Generator

Tags: php, html, cakephp, gd, newsletter

I've made a php newsletter (in CakePHP) generation script. You use an in-place editor and it generates an HTML which you use to send newsletter with. It works fine and dandy but now I've received a new design for the newsletter and I have some problems.

The biggest problems of them all are rounded corners, gradients, shadows and other font families (which aren't default). So it's pretty clear that I cannot use an HTML anymore as in the email body the < style > attribute is not allowed or is ignored (at least in GMail it's like that) and I was thinking of making the newsletter get generated using PHP GD (I would generate a number of images - for each block an image).

The problem is that it has to be done quick and to look good. To make a block look exactly like HTML would be killer in GD (a lot of refreshes and retries for each type of block) and it still would have some stupid font display issues.

I need a solution of some sort. I thought of making a script that would take a snapshot of the html but I can't see that happening.

Answer (score 1):

this is an email with rounded corners in gmail

[image: looks rounded to me]

you just need to think old school. you cant use css3 and html5 for email, but that has still been around for years... ala background images.

something like this http://www.nutrocker.co.uk/corners.html